# Best SPL Exception for file errors in PHP

Tags: php, file, exception, spl

I want to check if some directory is writable (it should be), and, if not, to throw a technical Exception like this:

```
if (!is_writable($new_dir)) {
  throw new SomeSPLException ("Bad!");
}
```

What type of standard PHP SPL Exception best suits in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After taking a look at the built in exceptions

http://php.net/manual/en/spl.exceptions.php and http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.exceptions.php

I would personally create my own as none really seem to fit

```
class NonWritableDirectoryException extends \Exception {}
```

Or maybe.. after a second glance.. I'd go for a `RuntimeException` and pass in a message such as "Unwritable directory", though I still think the first idea is the way to go